# PHP - Display message directly after selecting a Radio Button

Tags: php, javascript, html, radio-button, messagebox

I am using a PHP script, but say I had two radio buttons, right?

How could I actually execute code, such as (main intention | display a messagebox) upon selection of one or the other?

Say I had a radio button named `RadioButton1`, Once `checked/selected`, a `message box` would appear saying `RadioButton1 Selected`?

Is this possible through PHP alone? Or do I need to integrate an html page which posts to the PHP page?

Comment: It's not possible with PHP. Try JavaScript with AJAX

Comment: No, PHP is server-side, while what you want is client-side which is what JavaScript does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Javascript for client side interaction like that. The code below listens for the `onchange` event and shows an `alert()`.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JDMk9/)**

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="RadioButton1" />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="RadioButton2" />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="RadioButton3" />

<script>
​window.onload = function()
{
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("myradio");
     for(var i=0; i<radios.length; i++)
     {
        radios[i].onchange = function()
        {
            if(this.checked)
            {
                alert(this.value + " selected");
            }
        }
     }             
}​
</script>
```

The first 3 lines are the radio buttons HTML. After that we have the `<script>` tag which denotes [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) code. The Javascript is adding some code to the `onload` event, which simply means: execute this code when the page is loaded. Next we get all of the radio button elements into an array called `radios` - for that we use `getElementsByName()` passing the radio button group name which is `myradio`. Next we loop through each radio button in the array and assign an `onchange` handler, which means: execute this code when each radio button is changed. Within that, we check if the radio button is `checked` and if it is, we show the alert, showing the radio button's value which will be `RadioButton1`, `RadioButton2`, `RadioButton3`.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing response. I almost believe it is the final answer to my question...Yet, like stated before, I am no HTTP/HTML/PHP/JS/etc coder... I code Delphi, C++, VB, C#, etc..lol...Would it honestly be to much to ask for a bit more detail on the implementation of the code you have provided? Thank you for your posts. You have what looks to be HTML code there and then some code using the name "<script>"..Thanks, again/anyways....

Comment: Still working on the actual implementation, but you seem to know your shit. Your post is by far the most in detail. I appreciate it, but it does seem as if I still have a lot of work ahead of me to actually implement your code.

Comment: @JoshLine have a look at the jsFiddle demo, or just throw the code onto any HTML page and run it. This is pure Javascript, so it doesn't depend on any third party libraries. If you need any more help, let me know :)

Comment: I have thrown that exact script into an HTML and a PHP file..

Neither worked out. The three radio buttons show, but nothing happens upon selection of any of them.

Comment: Have a look in the error console to see if there's any Javascript errors. For example in Firefox: ctrl+shift+j or in Chrome: F12

Comment: Nothing of the sort. I checked all...In multiple browsers. :/ Sounds lame, I know, but I copy and pasted your code directly into HTML file, tested, and failed. Then in a PHP file, tested, and failed. I am unsure of what I am missing/doing wrong here. :/

Comment: Hmm, seems that when I copy the code form the question and paste into a file, a `?` is added at te start of the `window` line, that will cause an error so check if you have that and if you do - remove it.

Comment: Nothing of the sort on my side. I am unsure of how to message you privately, but if you can message me please, I will be most grateful, and giving. Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20233/discussion-between-mrcode-and-josh-line)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a form element is done in the client's browser, while PHP is a server-side language. It is absolutely unaware of what the user clicks until some data is actually sent back to the server, e.g., via a POST request upon submitting a form.

So no, PHP isn't capable of achieving what you are after.

There's an easy way though. JavaScript is executed on the client side, so you can easily attach an event listener to your radio buttons and display a message box if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with just php! Try using Jquery as the easiest was to do this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#radio-btn', function(){
    $.get( 'file1.php' , function (data) {
          //whatever you want to do after fetching the data from a php file
    }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using php alone its not possible, but you can do it using Jquery ajax. To do this make a ajax request on click of radio button, and populate the message box with the data comming in response.
Let me explain with an example:

```
<div id='msg_box'>Message will be displayed here</div>
```

on click of radio button call a function of javascript say ajaxCallForMessage()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxCallForMessage(){
$.ajax({
url: "Url of the page which contain message/?btn_name=xy",
 mthod: "GET"
}).done(function ( data ) {
$('#msg_box').append(data);
});
```

}

```
</script>
```

make sure you included jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question properly, I would suggest to do it simply via Javascript.

Once the user selects the RadioButton1, the "click" event is triggered in the page. I guess you know that you can capture it adding the `onClick` attribute like:

```
<input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="RadioOption1" onclick="showMessage()"> Option 1
```

Then all you need to do is to create a Javascript funcion `showMessage` that adds some html to the page (maybe a paragraph) with the message you want to display. You can do this in Javascript easily, using for example the jQuery append or html functions.

```
function showMessage() {
   // Example displaying an alert
   alert("Message to be displayed here")
}
```

I would only introduce PHP here if there is really a need to obtain information from the server. In this case what you should be doing is probably a GET / POST from the page to the server (e.g. using AJAX via jQuery [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method). You will call a PHP script that returns some information that then will be displayed in the page through Javascript.

But if all you need is to display a simple message like "Option 1 selected" you should do it in Javascript without server interaction.

I hope this helps.

Regards,
Romén